# Reusable UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want to avoid duplicate rewriting same code and create reusable UITableViewController.

I have ExerciseViewController with 3 buttons. Each button push a UITableViewController on the navigation stack. There are three UITableViewControllers: 1) **CategoryUITableVC**, 2) **EquipmentUITableVC**, 3) **MusclesUITableVC**.

All of these three view controllers have almost exactly same layout - cells with labels and accessory buttons. The only difference is that first view controller has got image next to title. Is it worth doing **one reusable VC** and instantiate it 3 times or maybe better solution create 3 separated VC (but It will be just rewriting almost same code).

I use coordinator pattern.

```
 class ExerciseCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
     
        var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
        var navigationController: UINavigationController
        
        ...   
        //unnecessary code to show
        ...    

     // *HERE I INSTANTIATE VIEW CONTROLLERS, I PRESENT THEM MODALLY BUT I WANT TO HAVE NAVIGATION BAR, SO I NEED TO CREATE NEW NAVIGATION CONTROLLERS*

    lazy var equipmentVC: ReusableTableViewController = {
        let vc = AppStoryboard.Main.instantiate(ReusableTableViewController.self)
        vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()
    
    lazy var equipmentNavController: UINavigationController = {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: equipmentVC)
        navController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        return navController
    }()
    
    lazy var categoryVC: ReusableTableViewController = {
        let vc = AppStoryboard.Main.instantiate(ReusableTableViewController.self)
        vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()
    
    lazy var categoryNavController: UINavigationController = {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: categoryVC)
        navController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        return navController
    }()

   lazy var muscleVC: ReusableTableViewController = {
        let vc = AppStoryboard.Main.instantiate(ReusableTableViewController.self)
        vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()
    
    lazy var muscleNavController: UINavigationController = {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: muscleVC)
        navController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        return navController
    }()

}

extension ExerciseCoordinator: CustomExerciseDelegate {
    
    func selectCategory() {
        navigationController.viewControllers.last?.present(categoryNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        categoryVC.dataType = .category
    }
    
    func selectEquipment() {
        navigationController.viewControllers.last?.present(equipmentNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        equipmentVC.dataType = .equipment
    }
    
    func selectMuscles() {
        navigationController.viewControllers.last?.present(muscleNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        muscleVC.dataType = .muscle
    }
}
```

I assign data type to know from where it comes from (CategoryVC/EquipmentVC/MuscleVC) when I will dismiss UITableVC.

Here it is my reusable UITableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ExerciseCategoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var delegate: ExerciseSelectionCriteriaDelegate?
    //I use it delegate to send data back after dismiss view
    
    var dataType: DataType?
    
    var data = [String]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData() }}
        }
        
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getData()
 
    }
    
    func getData() {
        
        if dataType == .category {
            let allCategories = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Category.self)
            data = allCategories.compactMap({$0.category})
        } else if dataType == .equipment {
            let allEquipment = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Equipment.self)
            data = allEquipment.compactMap({$0.equipment})
        } else {
            let allMuscles = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Muscles.self)
            data = allMuscles.compactMap({$0.muscles})
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// below is my own shortcut for dequeue cell, it works
        let cell: ExerciseSelectionTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueResuableCell(for: indexPath)
            cell.category.text = data[indexPath.row]
        
        if let image = UIImage(named: "\(data[indexPath.row].lowercased())") {
            cell.categoryImage.image = image
            cell.categoryImage.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.categoryImage.isHidden = true
        }
            
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
    
    @IBAction func closeViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        closeViewController()
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveSelectedCategories(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        saveSelectedData()
    }
  
    func saveSelectedData() {
        let selectedIndexes = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        if let selectedData = selectedIndexes?.compactMap({data[$0.row]}) {
                
                  dismiss(animated: true) {
                    
                    self.delegate?.selectedFields(for: selectedData, dataType: self.dataType)
                  }
              } else {
                  dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.delegate?.selectedFields(for: nil, dataType: self.dataType)
                  }
              }
    }
    
    func closeViewController() {
        guard let _ = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { return dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}
        
        Alert.showAlertWithCompletion(on: self, with: "TEXT", message: "TEXT") { _ in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
}
```

I will be thankful if you tell me if this approach is correct or maybe better solution are separated view controllers or create protocol with default implementation?

Comment: It looks (to me) like you are asking at least two questions. The first one - encapsulating code in either a `UIView` or `UIViewController` is easily answered. In fact (again, to me) you already answered it. By all means, do it! But at the right level (view or controller). But THAT, (again, to me) is your real question - do you want to instantiate multiple instances of `UINavigationController`? Please, remember the difference between a navigation bar (which is just a view) versus a navigation controller (which has child view controllers in a stack)....

Comment: /2 That last point is so important I wanted to add a second comment. (And sorry, a pet peeve for me is how loose some are between views versus controllers. Not sure you are doing this.) A navigation controller *uses* a navigation bar to push/pop it's view controller in a stack it maintains. A navigation bar is just that - a view. You *can* roll you own "stack" - that is, make it look like your table view has a detail view for certain cells - but that's up to you. It's just a view.

Comment: I create seperated navigation controller for each presented modally table view controller, because I want to obtain navigation bar (to get navigation bar buttons). I've read that is the only way to get nav bar od presented modally view. I've read in human guidelines that every vc presented modally should have button to dismiss view. So I have two way: create own buttons or create nav bar. Do you recommend to create buttons on modally presented view controllers (to make look similar to nav bar) instead of creating nav bar with nav bar buttons?

Comment: I guess the answer is "what do you think the user expects"? IMHO, the user - as of iOS 14 - expects the default behavior, which *is not* a full screen that requires a close button. (And I'm not good with that.) But if you *do* present things in full screen, where the user cannot swipe down or dismiss, than absolutely, you need a close button. But it's not needed to be in a nav bar. I have an app with a table view. This table view can be edited. The nav bar above it defaults to "Add" on the left that calls up a collection of thumbnails and "Edit" on the right.

Comment: /2 When the user taps "Add", the Edit button changes to "Cancel" until the a thumbnail is chosen. When The user taps "Edit" the add button disappears, the table view goes into edit mode (for delete and reordering) and the edit button changes to "Done". If I were to do this modally (it's an iPad app so it doesn't) I would put all of this inside my view controller's view being presented and add a "Close" button (think one of the five SF Symbols "xmark" flavors) at either the top left or right. As for which, now **that's** something too hot for me!